# .Net chatroom hash (eStreamChat)

Tags: c#, .net, hash, chat, sha

I have a question specific to [eStreamChat](http://www.estreamchat.com/) (An opensource Chatroom for .Net). There doesn't seem to be much in the way of documentation on their websites or any examples online so if anyone could help that would be great. I think that the problem is with my hash.

So far I have managed to download and import the project and set up a virtual IIS directory so that I can use it from my own application. I have created a link on one of my own webpages that brings me to their `ChatRoom.aspx` webpage. The link that brings me there is in the required format eg:

```
http://localhost:10833/eStreamChat/ChatRoom.aspx?id=lowens&timestamp=130425080917&hash=eb9fa849033cbf7b967ba472efb46363903f96dc
```

The page loads and I can see the chatroom but I get the following error popup: Unable to join room! Hash is invalid!

To get this far I have followed the instructions on [this page:](https://estreamchat.estreamdesk.com/forums/43879/topics/18421)

The only line I didn't understand was this: **You can configure the secret key from the web.config file** so maybe if somebody could explain what I'm supposed to be doing in the web.config it might help.

The error that is being thrown is from the `RemoteAuthUserProvider.cs`. Here is the code:

```
NameValueCollection hrefParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(hrefUri.Query);

var calculatedHash = Miscellaneous.CalculateChatAuthHash(hrefParams["id"] ?? String.Empty,
                hrefParams["target"] ?? String.Empty, hrefParams["timestamp"]);

if (hrefParams["hash"] != calculatedHash)
{
    throw new SecurityException("Hash is invalid!");
}
```

After debugging:

`hrefParams["hash"]` is "eb9fa849033cbf7b967ba472efb46363903f96dc" this is

`calculatedHash` is "5129cf1cf65350a387ce53a2b0d31c960f9d96d3"

So why is that hash not the same?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Web.config in appSettings a value is needed:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="AuthSecretKey" value="ENTER A VALUE HERE"/>
</appSettings>
```

This value needs to match the secretKey in the click method provided on the website so that the hashes will match.

Comment: Do you make it works now? I am having another problem regarding Microsoft.Practices.Unity.resources.dll is missing. Do you have any idea about this?